# Groupby with Apply Method in Pandas : Percentage Sum of Grouped Values

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I am trying to develop a program to convert daily data into monthly or yearly data and so on.
I have a DataFrame with datetime index and price change %:

```
                % Percentage
Date
2015-06-02      0.78
2015-06-10      0.32
2015-06-11      0.34
2015-06-12     -0.06
2015-06-15     -0.41
...
```

I had success grouping by some frequency. Then I tested:

```
 df.groupby('Date').sum()
 df.groupby('Date').cumsum()
```

If it was the case it would work fine, but the problem is that I can't sum it percent way (1+x0) * (1+x1)... -1.  Then I tried:

```
def myfunc(values):
    p = 0    
    for val in values:
        p = (1+p)*(1+val)-1
    return p

df.groupby('Date').apply(myfunc)
```

I can't understand how apply () works. It seems to apply my function to all data and not just to the grouped items.

Comment: Can you please show, what would be your expected output?

Comment: Sure. I just edited the post. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `apply` is applying to all rows individually because you're grouping by the `date` column. Your date column looks to have unique values for each row, so each group has only one row in it. You need to use a [`Grouper`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Grouper.html) to group by month, then use `cumprod` and get the last value for each group:

```
# make sure Date is a datetime
df["Date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["Date"])

# add one to percentages
df["% Percentage"] += 1

# use cumprod on each month group, take the last value, and subtract 1
df.groupby(pd.Grouper(key="Date", freq="M"))["% Percentage"].apply(lambda g: g.cumprod().iloc[-1] - 1)
```

Note, though, that this applies the percentage growth as if the steps between your rows were the same, but it looks like sometimes it's 8 days and sometimes it's 1 day. You may need to do some clean-up depnding on the result you want.